# Angle between planes challenging Question

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, 3d, plane-geometry

> The plane $r.(a,3,5)=10$ is inclined at an angle of $45^\circ$  to the plane $r.(-5,1,4)$

Find the value(s) of **$a$** up to $2$ decimal places.

I attempted this problem by forming an equation where I let the dot product of the two normal vectors divided by the magnitude of each of the normal vectors multiplied together equal to $\cos 45^\circ$ I tried to solve it on my graphics calculator, but it didn't seem to be able to find a solution.

How would one go about solving this problem??

Comment: What did you get as the normal vectors?

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track. Squaring both sides of 
$$(a,3,5)\cdot(-5,1,4)=\pm\|(a,3,5)\|\|(-5,1,4)\|\cos(45^\circ),$$
you get a quadratic equation in $a$.